# C# How to order dictionary<string, list<string>> by list.count?

Tags: c#, dictionary, count, sql-order-by

I have a `dictionary` where the value is a `list` of strings. And I want to order the dictionary by the number of strings in each `list`. So the first `kvp` I print is the `kvp` with the highest number of elements in the `list`.

I saw this answer under another question here in stackoverflow, but I think I am missing something.

```
foreach (var kvp in teams.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Count))
```

Comment: Could you please post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, but it sounds like you want descending:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var teams = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        teams.Add("Short List",  new List<string> {"One","Two"});
        teams.Add("Medium List", new List<string> {"One","Two", "Three"});
        teams.Add("Long List",   new List<string> {"One","Two", "Three", "Four"});

        foreach (var kvp in teams.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Count))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Team {0} has {1} items.", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Team Long List has 4 items.
Team Medium List has 3 items.
Team Short List has 2 items.
```

Check it out on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yQkRjY).